# ¿como ejecuto el sp que tiene un update desde asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp

tengo el siguiente inconveniente :
tengo una aplicación en 3 capas en la capa datos tengo el siguiente codigo :

```
 public string D_RegistroAprobacionRH(int vopt, string vObservacionVrh, string vUsuarioValidarh, string vObservacionArh, string vUsuarioApruebarh, string vObservacionLogistica, string vUsuarioApruebaLogist)
  {
      try
      {
          string _bol = "";

          sqlconx = new SqlConnection();
          sqlconx.ConnectionString = vConec.conxWebProd;

          dt = new DataTable();
          dAdap = new SqlDataAdapter();
          cmd = new SqlCommand();

          cmd.Connection = sqlconx;
          cmd.CommandTimeout = 7000000;
          cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
          cmd.CommandText = "Usp_RegitroValidacion";

          cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Opt", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = vopt;
          cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Observacionvrh", SqlDbType.VarChar,150)).Value = vObservacionVrh;
          cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Usuariovrh", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30)).Value = vUsuarioValidarh;
          cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ObservacionArh", SqlDbType.VarChar, 150)).Value = vObservacionArh;
          cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UsuarioArh", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30)).Value = vUsuarioApruebarh;
          cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ObservaLogi", SqlDbType.VarChar, 150)).Value = vObservacionLogistica;
          cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UsuarioAprlog", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30)).Value = vUsuarioApruebaLogist;

          dt.Clear();
          dt.Reset();

          if (sqlconx.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
          {
              sqlconx.Open();

          }

         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

         sqlconx.Close();

          return _bol ;

      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {

          throw new Exception(ex.Message);
      }
```

en la capa negocios tengo el siguiente código :

```
 public string B_RegistraAprobacionrh(int vopt, string vObservacionVrh, string vUsuarioValidarh, string vObservacionArh, string vUsuarioApruebarh, string vObservacionLogistica, string vUsuarioApruebaLogist)
   {
       return vDregistraValida.D_RegistroAprobacionRH(vopt, vObservacionVrh, vUsuarioValidarh, vObservacionArh, vUsuarioApruebarh, vObservacionLogistica, vUsuarioApruebaLogist);

   }
```

en la presentación tengo el siguiente código que es donde me muestra un error:

```
protected void btnaprobarrh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Exec = "";

        Exec= vB_ApruebaRRHH.B_RegistraAprobacionrh(2, "", "", "", Session["Usuario"].ToString(), "", "");
        btnaprobarrh.Enabled = false;
        btnDescargar.Enabled = false;



        Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('Aprobación Registrada Correctamente...!');</script>");

    }
```

me muestra el siguiente mensaje : 
Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.
[image: Error]

Comment: Verifica que la Session de usuario exista `if(Session["Usuario"] != null)` antes de realizar la ejecución

Comment: Gracias, pero ya lo hice e igual me indica el mismo mensaje : Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.

Comment: Donde estas creando vB_ApruebaRRHH? Es un error de nulls, los errores de nulls se solucionan revisando que objetos estás usando.

Comment: Si tenias razón, @hardkoded muchas gracias por la ayuda, ya lo solucione!